# Multiple Context path for the same war in jboss

Tags: web, jboss, jboss6.x, contextroot

I am deploying my web app in  `jboss-EAP-6.1`

I would like to have different context path for the same war:

```
http://localhost:8080/path1/xyx

http://localhost:8080/path2/xyx
```

Can you please suggest me on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pin your application via jboss-web.xml to context-root path1 and add rewrite rule to standalone.xml as shown:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
  <alias name="localhost"/>
  <rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^/path1(.*)$" substitution="/path2/$1" flags="NC"/>
</virtual-server>
```

Comment: I tried this with jboss AS 7, and I had two errors, first one was unrecognized attribute 'name', which I fixed by just removing the name attribute from the rewrite node, then it deployed successfully but the rewrite failed because it was appending // after the path2 so I had to remove the / between path2 and $1
the final configuration was this:
<rewrite pattern="^/path1(.*)$" substitution="/path2$1" flags="NC"/>
after this it was all successful and working perfectly... so thank you for the tip!